# Call a JS function when a views ajax request completes?

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I want to run some JS stuff on the exposed filters of a view which uses ajax. How can I know every time the view is reloaded by ajax, and run some JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find ahah/ajax success by this function.

**Not a Drupal Way.**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
 $('body').bind('ajaxSuccess', function(data, status, xhr) {
  alert('Ajax Success');
 });
});
```

This function will get invoked on every ajax success.

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal Way**

Create own module
Implement hook_views_ajax_data_alter() in it
For ex. if your module has name 'mymodule', code will be

```
function mymodule_views_ajax_data_alter(&$commands, $view)
{
    $commands[] = array('command' => 'customCommand');
}
```

and add your JS stuff to this command

```
(function ($) {
  if (Drupal.ajax) {
    Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.customCommand = function (ajax, response, status) {
//JS stuff
console.log(response);
    };
  }

}) (jQuery);
```